# Display array values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

So, I'm working with PHP for the first time and I am trying to retrieve and display the values of an array. After a lot of googling, the only methods I can find for this are `print_r`, `var_dump` or `var_export`. However, all of these methods return something that looks like this:

```
[a] => apple
[b] => banana
[c] => orange
```

I can't figure out how to style this outout. I need to strip away the `[a] =>` part and add commas. I know this must be a pretty straightforward process but I haven't been able to track down any documentation that demonstrates how to do it.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

There is [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop in php. You have to traverse the array.

```
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
  echo $key." has the value". $value;
}
```

If you simply want to add commas between values, consider using [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
$string=implode(",",$array);
echo $string;
```

Answer (score 20):

You can use implode to return your array with a string separator.

```
$withComma = implode(",", $array);

echo $withComma;
// Will display apple,banana,orange
```

Answer (score 14):

```
<?php $data = array('a'=>'apple','b'=>'banana','c'=>'orange');?>
<pre><?php print_r($data); ?></pre>
```

**Result:** 
Array
(
          [a] => apple
          [b] => banana
          [c] => orange
)

---

Sorry for the above, I read it too quickly and misunderstood.

```
<?php
$fruites = array('apple', 'banana', 'orange');
echo implode(',',$fruites);
?>
```

**Result:** 
apple,banana,orange

Comment: This result is exactly what he doesn't want, he wants to output the plain values without array formatting.

Comment: Sorry, I read it wrong. So I didn't answer correctly as he asked. I fixed it now.

Answer (score 7):

the [`join()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.join.php) function must work for you:

```
$array = array('apple','banana','ananas');
$string = join(',', $array);
echo $string;
```

Output :

> apple,banana,ananas

Answer (score 5):

a simple code snippet that i prepared, hope it will be usefull for you;

```
$ages = array("Kerem"=>"35","Ahmet"=>"65","Talip"=>"62","Kamil"=>"60");

reset($ages);

for ($i=0; $i < count($ages); $i++){
echo "Key : " . key($ages) . " Value : " . current($ages) . "<br>";
next($ages);
}
reset($ages);
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It looks like a reasonable answer. (although I haven't tried it)

Answer (score 4):

use `implode(',', $array);` for output as `apple,banana,orange`

Or

```
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
   echo $key." is ". $value;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Iterate over the array and do whatever you want with the individual values.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . ' contains ' . $value . '<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can easily use join()

```
$fruits = array("apple", "banana", "orange");
print join(" ".$fruits);
```

Comment: and you can replace the space by a comma if you want (notice `join` is an alias of `implode`)

Answer (score 2):

Other option:

```
$lijst=array(6,4,7,2,1,8,9,5,0,3);
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
echo $lijst[$i];
echo "<br>";
}
```