# array to string conversion error in codeginiter in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

```
$data = array('first_name' => $this->input->post('fname'),
'middle_name' => $this->input->post('mname'),

'last_name' => $this->input->post('lname'),
'email_name' => $this->input->post('email'),
'pwd_name' => $this->input->post('pwd'),

    'cno_name' => $this->input->post('cno'),
    'gender_name' => $this->input->post('gender'),
    'country_name' => $this->input->post('country'),
    'lang_name' => $this->input->post('lang')

);
            echo $data;
```

i want to echo or print $data, but it showing error  Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Comment: You're looking for `print_r` or `var_dump` instead

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672796/display-array-values-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method 1**

```
foreach($data as $key => $val)
    echo($key.' => '.(is_array($val)?implode(',', $val):$val).'<br>');
```

**Method 2**

```
var_dump($data);
```

**Method 3**

```
print_r($data);
```

Comment: lang_name contain multiselect, all values are printing except lang_name.How can i print this variable also?                                        <input type="checkbox" name="lang[]" value="Telugu"  /> Telugu<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="lang[]" value="Hindi" />  Hindi<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="lang[]" value="English" />  English<br>

Comment: Which method are you using?

Answer (score 0):

1) your trying to echo the **array** variable ($data)

2) your not able to use **echo** for array variable

**solution:**

3) you can use **var_dump($data)** or **print_r($data)**.

Comment: lang_name contain multiselect, all values are printing except lang_name.How can i print this variable also?                                        <input type="checkbox" name="lang[]" value="Telugu"  /> Telugu<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="lang[]" value="Hindi" />  Hindi<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="lang[]" value="English" />  English<br>

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array('first_name' => $this->input->post('fname'),
'middle_name' => $this->input->post('mname'),

'last_name' => $this->input->post('lname'),
'email_name' => $this->input->post('email'),
'pwd_name' => $this->input->post('pwd'),

    'cno_name' => $this->input->post('cno'),
    'gender_name' => $this->input->post('gender'),
    'country_name' => $this->input->post('country'),
    'lang_name' => $this->input->post('lang')

);
```

### Now There is foreach loop in php. You have to traverse the array.

```
    foreach($data  as $key => $value)
    {
      echo $key." has the value". $value;
    }
```

### If you simply want to add commas between values, consider using implode

```
    $string=implode(",",$data);
    echo $string;
```

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="lang[]" value="Telugu"  /> Telugu<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="lang[]" value="Hindi" />  Hindi<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="lang[]" value="English" />  English<br>

in above array, lang_name contain multiselect, in foreach loop its not getting print

Comment: @Danush you could change the field name.

Comment: lang_name contain multiselect, all values are printing except lang_name.How can i print this variable also?                                        <input type="checkbox" name="lang[]" value="Telugu"  /> Telugu<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="lang[]" value="Hindi" />  Hindi<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="lang[]" value="English" />  English<br>

Comment: Get them like this: substr(implode(', ', $this->input->post('lang')), 0)

Comment: you can also use like this $this->input->post('lang');  It will be an array, the same thing as $_POST['lang'].   Example foreach ($this->input->post('lang') as $key => $value)
{
    echo "Index {$key}'s value is {$value}.";
}  Unfortunately, if you need to access a specific index, you'll have to lang it to a variable first or use $_POST instead of $this->input->post(). Example: $assign = $this->input->post('lang');
echo $assign[0]; // First value
echo $_POST['lang'][0];