# Echo a child of array

Tags: php

This is my php code for showing Book an Books numbers: (This is example)

```
<?php
$age=array("Peter"=>array("Book"=>"37","Books"=>"47"),"Ben"=>"37","Joe"=>"43");

echo "Book = " . $Peter['Book'] . ". And Books = "  . $Peter['Books'];
?>
```

**Result:**  Book = 37 And Books = 47

But I have receive error. Where is problem?

Comment: The array name is age. the first subarray is Peter, then book is an value. So: $age['Peter']['Book'] , https://3v4l.org/GbZMI

Comment: The variable `$Peter` is not defined. You probably mean `$age['Peter']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the values of the array use the following:

`$age['Peter']['Book']` instead of `$Peter['Book']`

and

`$age['Peter']['Books']` instead of `$Peter['Books']`.

Comment: Ben and Joe’s values are not an array, so just changing the name won’t work.

Comment: And new question: How can i print Book and Books number without write Books or Books.(If i have many child?)

Comment: @Alireza Please use a search engine before asking! Most of the time you can find a already asked question with an answer. But for you look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672796/display-array-values-in-php

Comment: @ishegg you're halfway right: there in the age array, but they do not have the properties book and books; but I edited my answer, so thanks for stating out 

Comment: That’s what I mean. You said “just change the names”, and `$age["Joe"]["Book"]` will throw an error.

Comment: @ishegg okay then I misunderstood it as Ben an Joe not even being in the age array. Anyway it's changed and we're good :)