# Explode is showing Array when i try to fetch and display comma separated value from database

Tags: php

I am storing the IDs of names with implode() function and comma separated like 1,3. Column name is diet_id(varchar) and it has values 1,3.
Now i want to fetch and display these IDs and their names like ID1 is ABC and ID2 is XYZ. I am using explode function to fetch and display but it returns me Array.
Here is what i did so far

Fetching

```
<?php
$ShowProducts = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM food WHERE merchant_id='$userId'");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($ShowProducts)){
// Getting Names from IDs
$Diet_query     = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM diets WHERE id=".$row['diet_id']);
$main_diet      = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Diet_query);
$ar = explode(' ',$main_diet); 
?>
```

Now displaying

```
<td><?php echo $ar;?></td>
```

but it returns me Array

Comment: If you store them with a Comma, you should also explode them with a Comma :)

Comment: `explode()` takes a string and returns it as an array of pieces. What did you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked my above query with var_dump(), it was bringing no data. When entry is only 1 in the table like 5, then it was showing data but with 3.5.2, it was showing null.
changed my query to this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM food";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$ids = $row["diet_id"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM diets WHERE id IN ($ids)";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while ($drow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$diet_name[] = $drow['diet_full_name'];
}
```

and then

```
<td><?php echo implode(", ", $diet_name);?></td>
```

It worked then

Answer (score 1):

`explode()` always returns an array. In your example the single values are 1 and 3 (exploded from `1,3`). Therefore the array will have two fields. One with the value `1` and one with the value `3`.

The text "Array" is the standard string representation of an array in PHP. If you want to print out the values individually you can use their indexes (starting with 0):

```php
<td><?php echo $ar[0];?></td>
<td><?php echo $ar[1];?></td>
```

There also many many other ways how to display array data, also see [this question for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672796/display-array-values-in-php).

Side note: In your post you are exploding the values by space and not by comma, so you might want to change your call to the `explode()` function accordingly if the value is actually stored with a comma as you said:

```php
$ar = explode(' ',$main_diet);
```

should be:

```php
$ar = explode(',',$main_diet);
```